# ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.protobuf.ByteString"

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

My Project use Firebase Firestore and in has ran perfectly until 3 days ago, i tested whole my project and Booom... I don't know what happen but my app crash weirdly with a weird error.

```
  E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.teamttdvlp.memolang, PID: 32467
java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Cloud Firestore (21.3.0).
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$panic$3(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:529)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$$Lambda$3.run(Unknown Source:2)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6694)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/protobuf/ByteString;
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.WriteStream.<clinit>(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:52)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLiteMutationQueue.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:95)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLitePersistence.getMutationQueue(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:166)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LocalStore.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:138)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient.initialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:271)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient.lambda$new$0(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:108)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient$$Lambda$1.run(Unknown Source:8)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$enqueue$2(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:431)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$$Lambda$2.call(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor.lambda$executeAndReportResult$1(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:317)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$$Lambda$2.run(Unknown Source:4)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$DelayedStartFactory.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:224)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.protobuf.ByteString" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.teamttdvlp.memolang-hk2tKyVJBtKM-j-8nqhQ9A==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.teamttdvlp.memolang-hk2tKyVJBtKM-j-8nqhQ9A==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
```

Here is my Gradle File (Module app)

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

  apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

  apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

  apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

  android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.teamttdvlp.memolang"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dataBinding {
    enabled true
}
  }

  dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'

// ConstraintLayout
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2'

// View Model
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:$rootProject.viewModelVersion"
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$rootProject.viewModelVersion"
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:common:$rootProject.viewModelVersion"
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:$rootProject.viewModelVersion"

// Testing
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

// Firebase
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1'

// Google Authentication
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'

// Firebase Authentication
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'

// Firebase Firestore
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.3.0'

// Facebook Authentication
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:5.5.1'

//  Dagger 2
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$rootProject.dagger2Version"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$rootProject.dagger2Version"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$rootProject.dagger2Version"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$rootProject.dagger2Version"

// navigation
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.1.0'

// room
def room_version = "2.2.0-alpha02"
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

} apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And here is Gralde File (Project Application)

```
  buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.31'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
  }

  allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
  }

  ext {
dagger2Version = '2.24'
viewModelVersion = '2.2.0-alpha02'
  }

  task clean(type: Delete) {
      delete rootProject.buildDir
  }
```

The error says that It can't resolve com.google.protobuf.ByteString class, so i checked the library and it really didn't there
[image]

Any idea to fix this problem ?

Comment: Something you can try:
1/ Rebuild the project. 
2/ Android Studio -> File -> Invalidate caches / Restart. 
3/ Remove the `build` folder in module level

Comment: Yep I am. Hi there man
Usually when I met this kind of error. I will try to clear all the cache (rebuild project, resync Gradle...). If it's a release build may be some Proguard config is missing. Check the document and configure the lib again may help. Good luck there

Comment: Yeah !!! Actually, i thought like you, so i did create new project then i copied all code and resources from the old to the new one, just hope that it can fix some building error. But i am now still stuck in that weird ByteString class :)) So funny. Anyway, thanks for your advices.